# newline in title on first page but not on subsequent pages

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, titles

My title had only one word on the second line and it looked weird so I fixed it by adding `\\` in the appropriate place.  Now on the odd-numbered pages where the title is at the top, it has a really long space where the newline is.  How do I keep the title the way it is on the title page but change it on subsequent pages?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\title{this title had one lonely word \\but I fixed it with newline}
\author{emily}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{content goes here}
\newpage
\section{but now I have a problem on odd-numbered pages}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
\title[this title had one lonely word but I fixed it with newline]
      {this title had one lonely word \\but I fixed it with newline}
```