# Beamer presentation: title on subsequent slides not taken from [] but from {}

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles, themes

Following e.g., this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58377/114622 I found out and tested in other presentations `\title[what comes on subsequent slides]{what is the title on the title slide}`

However, in a template this is not happening. It will always show the title in {} on following pages.

How can I add this []-title feature back to the template?

The template in question:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unix Beamer Style
% 2018-09-06
% 

\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\mode<presentation>

\newdimen\beamer@uxBorderHeight
\newdimen\beamer@uxTitleHeight
\newdimen\beamer@uxFooterHeight
\newdimen\beamer@uxOverlap

\beamer@uxOverlap=0.2pt
\beamer@uxBorderHeight=0.015\paperheight
\beamer@uxTitleHeight=0.185\paperheight
%DEFAULT: 
%\beamer@uxTitleHeight=0.125\paperheight
\beamer@uxFooterHeight=0.032\paperheight

\definecolor{uxRed}{HTML}{E6002E}
\definecolor{uxGrey}{RGB}{217,217,217}

\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{date in title page}{fg=black}

% set fonts
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi



\setbeamerfont*{structure}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{title}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=uxRed}
\setbeamerfont*{subtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamerfont*{author}{size*={10}{12},series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{institute}{size*={10}{12}}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont*{date}{size*={8}{10}}
\setbeamerfont*{headline}{size*={8}{10}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{unix}{%
  % list trick from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly
  \begin{list}{}{
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}}
  \item[]
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  {\usebeamerfont*{title}\color{uxRed}\inserttitle\par} % no idea why usebeamercolor{title} does not work here
  {\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}
  {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par}
  {\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par}
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  \end{list}
%  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{unix}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth+10pt}
   \setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
   \setlength{\lineskip}{-\beamer@uxOverlap}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
   \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{1}{
    \raisebox{-\height-2\beamer@uxBorderHeight}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace*{0.86\paperwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.125\paperwidth]{uxlogo.pdf}}
   }{}
   
      \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
        \ifdefempty{\insertframesubtitle}{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+\beamer@uxTitleHeight}\\
          \color{white}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-\beamer@uxTitleHeight-\beamer@uxFooterHeight-6ex}
        }{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+2\beamer@uxTitleHeight}\\          
          \color{white}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-2\beamer@uxTitleHeight-\beamer@uxFooterHeight-6ex}   
        }
   }{}
   

  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{unix}{% 
    \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
      \vspace{3.5ex}
      \hspace{4.5ex}\inserttitle
    }{}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{unix}{
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\vspace{0.5ex}
\raggedright
\vspace{3.5ex}
{\insertframetitle\par}
{\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\end{minipage}
}


% set bullets

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{unix}{$\bullet$}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{unix}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=4ex}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=4ex}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \begin{frame}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    \begin{center}
  

    \end{center}

    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
  \end{frame}
}

\mode<all>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template uses `\inserttitle` in the headline. If you want it to insert the short title, you can use `\insertshorttitle` instead (if no short title is given, this will automatically fall back to the full title).

Please note that setting the headline conditionally with `\ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{}{}` is a spectacularly bad idea, because beamer calculates the frame geometry at the start of the document and thus assumes a wrong height of the headline. A bit less bad would be to test if the framenumber is 1, but ideally you'll remove this test completely and instead either use the `plain` frame option for the first frame or use a special headline e.g. for the title page using the same trick as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1004#a1198 .

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unix Beamer Style
% 2018-09-06
% 

\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\mode<presentation>

\newdimen\beamer@uxBorderHeight
\newdimen\beamer@uxTitleHeight
\newdimen\beamer@uxFooterHeight
\newdimen\beamer@uxOverlap

\beamer@uxOverlap=0.2pt
\beamer@uxBorderHeight=0.015\paperheight
\beamer@uxTitleHeight=0.185\paperheight
%DEFAULT: 
%\beamer@uxTitleHeight=0.125\paperheight
\beamer@uxFooterHeight=0.032\paperheight

\definecolor{uxRed}{HTML}{E6002E}
\definecolor{uxGrey}{RGB}{217,217,217}

\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{date in title page}{fg=black}

% set fonts
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi



\setbeamerfont*{structure}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{title}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=uxRed}
\setbeamerfont*{subtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamerfont*{author}{size*={10}{12},series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{institute}{size*={10}{12}}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=uxRed}
\setbeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont*{date}{size*={8}{10}}
\setbeamerfont*{headline}{size*={8}{10}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{unix}{%
  % list trick from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly
  \begin{list}{}{
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}}
  \item[]
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  {\usebeamerfont*{title}\color{uxRed}\inserttitle\par} % no idea why usebeamercolor{title} does not work here
  {\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}
  {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par}
  {\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par}
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  \end{list}
%  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{unix}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth+10pt}
   \setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
   \setlength{\lineskip}{-\beamer@uxOverlap}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
   \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{1}{
    \raisebox{-\height-2\beamer@uxBorderHeight}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace*{0.86\paperwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.125\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}
   }{}
   
      \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
        \ifdefempty{\insertframesubtitle}{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+\beamer@uxTitleHeight}\\
          \color{white}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-\beamer@uxTitleHeight-\beamer@uxFooterHeight-6ex}
        }{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+2\beamer@uxTitleHeight}\\          
          \color{white}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-2\beamer@uxTitleHeight-\beamer@uxFooterHeight-6ex}   
        }
   }{}
   

  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{unix}{% 
%    \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{1}{}{
      \vspace{3.5ex}
      \hspace{4.5ex}\insertshorttitle
%    }
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{unix}{
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\vspace{0.5ex}
\raggedright
\vspace{3.5ex}
{\insertframetitle\par}
{\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\end{minipage}
}


% set bullets

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{unix}{$\bullet$}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{unix}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=4ex}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=4ex}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \begin{frame}[plain]
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    \begin{center}
  

    \end{center}

    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
  \end{frame}
}

\mode<all>

\makeatother

\title[short]{title}

\begin{document}

    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ftitle}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that insertshorttitle worked like a charm! Maybe the ifnumgreater thing will also solve my problem that I always have an empty page at the start. I will try it =)

Comment: @canIchangethis The empty page at the start is caused by the code in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` -- no idea what the purpose of this empty frame was ...

Comment: Thanks, all fixed now =)

Comment: @canIchangethis You're welcome!